# $_POST in PHP is not working, only empty values

Tags: php, json, post

I am developing an application in php, it receives a POST with information that I must process. I am in my development environment but I cannot test the app, it always returns empty.

in this way I capture the values ​​received in the php file

```
$nombre             = $_POST['nombre'];
$razon_social       = $_POST['razon_social'];
$apellido_paterno   = $_POST['apellido_paterno'];
$apellido_materno   = $_POST['apellido_materno'];
$rut                = $_POST['rut'];
$email              = $_POST['email'];
$telefono           = $_POST['telefono'];
$fecha_nacimiento   = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$comuna             = $_POST['comuna'];
$ciudad             = $_POST['ciudad'];
```

I use thunder from visual studio code to perform the tests, as follows

[image]

and when i try this to see de data

[image]

the response is only ------------ (the separators between echoes)

what im doing wrong ?

Comment: You are sending JSON. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369

Comment: P.S. For future reference please do not upload pictures of code or data. It's specifically forbidden - see [ask], and for good reason. Also, visual studio and visual studio code are separate products, and neither of them is especially relevant to your question, so I removed the erroneous visual-studio tag.